# JQuery/javascript: How to run a 'complete' eventlistener on a custom function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, event-handling

I have the following call

```
$('.fblikes span').fblikecount();


$.fn.fblikecount = function(){

    //DO SOME JSON XHR stuff to get FB like counts and update the # on page ...
}
```

which will run through all my fblikes classes (about 30) and run my 'socialscore' function on them, which basically updates the facebook like count for each one.

After **ALL** of them are completed, I wanted to run another function, I was thinking a callback is the way to go and have it run as an eventlistener for when the facebooklikecount() function is completed for all iterations of the .fblikes class.  I can succussfully run a callback for each individual call of fblikecount but I just want to run the callback **ONCE when ALL** of the fblikecount functions have completed.

My ideal solution would be something like this

```
$('.fblikes span').fblikecount().on( "complete", function() {
  //do something
});
```

Possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a counter... And an Ajax global event like [`.ajaxComplete()`](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/).

```
// Start by counting how many element are targetted.
var fblikesTotal = $('.fblikes span').length;

// Your function call.
$('.fblikes span').fblikecount();

// Your function.
$.fn.fblikecount = function(){

    //DO SOME JSON XHR stuff to get FB like counts and update the # on page ...

}

// On each ajax request completed
// Decrement fblikesTotal
// And check if it is all done.
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function(){

  // Decrement fblikesTotal
  fblikesTotal--;

  if(fblikesTotal==0){

    // Call your second function here.
    // ...

  }
});
```

Comment: I know it is accepted answer already but consider using reading on $.when to wrap multiple $.ajax calls. You will end up with a lot cleaner code. Also your code is broken if there are other ajax requests being performed ( and I bet they are, since you are using social buttons).

Answer (score 0):

Here is simpliest way I can think off:

```
$('.fblikes span').fblikecount();

function myAjaxThing() {

}

$.fn.fblikecount = function(options){
   var settings = $.extend({
        callback: function() {},
    }, options );

   var buttons = this.find('.....')

   $.when(buttons.map(myAjaxThing)).then(options.callback)

    return this;
}
```

If you want to handle named events, consider using namespaced events:

```
$.fn.fblikecount = function(options){
   var self = this;
   var settings = $.extend({
        callback: function() {},
    }, options );

   var buttons = this.find('.....')

   $.when(buttons.map(myAjaxThing)).then(function(ret) {
      self.trigger('complete.fblike', [ret])
   })

   return this;
}


$('.fblikes span').fblikecount().on( "complete.fblike", function() {
   //this will trigger now
});
```